# Unity InputField string comparison not working

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, input

I'm making a game where the user inputs a code, and if the code is correct, it opens a door. So, I made a InputField where the user inputs his answer and then I take his answer and compare it in this code:

```
public TextMeshProUGUI input;
public string answer;

public void retrieveText()
    {
        string userInput = input.text;

        //the code is made of letters so I make it all caps to not make it case sensitive
        userInput.ToUpper();

        if (userInput.Equals(answer))
        {
            //do stuff
        }
```

However, *userInput.Equals(answer)* always returns false, no matter what I try. I tried removing the *ToUpper()* function, using *userInput == answer*, and nothing works. if I use *Debug.Log* to see what *userInput* returns, it returns the correct answer. I hope someone can help me. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found it! As it turns out, you must use `TMP_InputField` class and not `TextMeshProUGUI`
to extract your text. Change that and everything works fine.

Comment: THANK YOU

I lost three hours to that crappy trap. Debugging the TextMeshProUGUI returns an identical string but fails to return true when compared with another identical string. 

As you worked out, changing it to the TMP_InputField  made it magic behind the scenes Very frustrating and counter institutive.